# Including an image in letter recipient address

Tags: graphics, positioning, letters, addresses

I've found answers for including graphics in every other part of a letter, but I can't seem to get a letter to compile when including a graphic in the recipient's address. I like to do this for cover letters, including the company's logo above their address.

```
\begin{letter}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{logo.png}
        \\123 Recipient Street
        \\City, State }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In order for people to be able to help you, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: handrawn sketch would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the value of the first line of the `letter` environment argument is used internally for several things, including setting headers and writing the recipient address to the `.aux` file as a string. If the value is something complex such as an `\includegraphics` command then this extra processing does not succeed.

The solution that requires the least amount of changes to the code (which will however not work properly if you actually use things like headers and return addresses) is to provide a placeholder for the recipient name, and only locally define the name as the image when it is being used for printing the recipient information, which is in the `\opening` macro. The macro where the name is stored is called `\toname` so this needs to be modified.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\signature{John Smith}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville}
\begin{document}
% provide a placeholder here
\begin{letter}{img-placeholder\\
        123 Recipient Street\\
        City, State}
\begingroup
% locally (i.e., within a group) define \toname to be an image
\def\toname{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}}
% use the image in the opening
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
% close the group, so \toname will be reset to the previous value (which is 'img-placeholder')
\endgroup
This is a letter.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]